# ¿es normal que la instalación de mongoose ocupe mas de 900Mb?

Tags: nodejs, mongoose, npm

Buen día, me encuentro aprendiendo nodejs y específicamente trabajando con mongoose, sin embargo en las aplicaciones donde lo he instalado aparece con un tamaño mayor a 900Mb; al buscar en la ruta:
..\MiApp1\node_modules\mongoose\tools
aparecen 3 directorios de nombre:  30000 , 30001 , 30002  cada una con un tamaño de 300Mb y a su vez contienen un directorio  journal  que contiene archivos 
WiredTigerLog.0000000001 
con tamaños superiores a 100Mb; si bien creo que son archivos de logs considero un tamaño desproporcionado para un paquete recién instalado.

Mi pregunta es ¿Son normales estos archivos y no presentaran problemas en caso de desplegar la aplicación?
la versión mongoose usada es: 4.10.6

Gracias.

Comment: WiredTiger es el motor de almacenamiento de MongoDB a partir de la versión 3.2. El asunto es que, en todo caso, esos logs deberían estar en el directorio de instalación, no en mongoose. Si los eliminas y vuelves a correr la app, ¿los crea nuevamente?

Comment: Gracias por su comentario,explicare las prueba que he hecho: cree una aplicación (conceptual)  llamada MiApp1, instale el paquete mongoose e ingrese a la ruta y aparecen los 3 directorios ya mencionados en la pregunta. Si creo otra aplicación MiAppp2 y la ejecuto, ya NO se crea estos directorio dentro de la ruta de MiAppp2. Si elimino MiApp1 y ejecuto MiApp2 entonces SI se crean los directorios dentro de MiApp2. si bien esto no afecta el funcionamiento del la app, me preocupa que al momento de que lo quiera montar en un servidor real tendré que disponer de mas de un 1GB solo para mongoose?